# php router works on mamp but doesn't work on live server

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I have been learning MVC system and I would say I have learned quite useful things. I have been doing all this using mamp and decided to see the routing working on a live server but the router just doesn't work. It still runs(?) the index.php file, however it does not make the controller work. I have been trying to solve this for 3 days now and as far as I understand (tried to echo to see where the code stops) it stops at a particular if statement in route.php.

I don't know if it is relevant but here is the website that I am trying to make this work: https://kalass.org and I am getting no php errors so that is not the reason why it doesn't make the function index run in HomeController.php. (The same codes are working on MAMP)

## index.php

```
<?php
//require __DIR__ ."/database.php";
//require __DIR__ ."/model.php";
require __DIR__. '/route.php';
require __DIR__. '/controller/controller.php';

Route::run("/","HomeController@index");
```

## route.php

```
<?php

class Route {
    public static function parse_url(){
        $dirname= dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
    $basename=basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
    $request_uri=str_replace([$dirname,$basename], null, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    return $request_uri;
    }

    public static function run($url,$callback,$method="GET"){

        $method =explode('|', strtoupper($method));
        if (in_array($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"],$method)){

        

        $patterns= [
            '{url}'=>'([0-9a-zA-Z]+)',
            '{id}'=> '([0-9]+)'
        ];

        $url= str_replace(array_keys($patterns), array_values($patterns),$url);

        $request_uri=self::parse_url();
        if (preg_match('@^'.$url.'$@',$request_uri,$parameters)){ //this is where the code stops working, after this if statement
            unset($parameters[0]);
            
            if (is_callable($callback)){
                call_user_func_array($callback, $parameters);

            }
            $controller= explode('@',$callback);
            $className=explode('/',$controller[0]);
            $className=end($className);
            $controllerFile=__DIR__."/controller/".strtolower($controller[0]).'.php';
             if (file_exists($controllerFile)){
                require $controllerFile;
                call_user_func_array([new $className,$controller[1]],$parameters);
             }

        }
    }
}
}
```

## controller.php

```
<?php


class Controller{
    
    public function view($name, $result=null,$data=null,$redirect=null){
        
        function showMessage(){
            if (isset($_SESSION["message"])){
                echo $_SESSION["message"];
                unset($_SESSION["message"]);
            }
        }
        $result=$result;
        $data=$data;
        if (isset($redirect)){
            header("Location:/project/$redirect");
        }
        require __DIR__."/../view/" . strtolower($name). '.php';
    }
    public function model($name){
        require  __DIR__."/../model/" . strtolower($name). '.php';
        return new $name();
    }
    
}
```

## HomeController.php

```
<?php

class HomeController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        
        $this->view("home");
    }
}
```

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Edit: So it doesn't go into the `if (preg_match('@^'.$url.'$@',$request_uri,$parameters))` statement in `route.php`. I used `var_dump();` function to see what are the values of the variables in the statement, and here are the results:
(used the `var_dump();` function just before the mentioned if statement.)

```
var_dump($url) --> string(1) "/" 
var_dump($request_uri)--> string(0) "" 
var_dump($parameters)--> NULL
```

Comment: `it stops at a particular if statement in route.php`...would you like to tell us which one? And have you got error logging switched on, so you can see any resulting errors / warnings in the error log file, and have you looked for errors? When it "stops", what http response is returned? e.g. 200, 400, 500, or what (your browser's network tools can tell you, if nothing else does)?

Comment: Is the .htaccess file definitely configured to be used in both places? This is a server config issue not PHP, can you post the webserver config?

Comment: I have commented the line in route.php, which is `if (preg_match('@^'.$url.'$@',$request_uri,$parameters))`. There are no php errors, as I mentioned I have checked. And by saying "stops", it doesnt go further in the code thus doesn't run the code on `HomeController.php`. But the codes in index.php runs flawlessly (it works when I echo, for instance.)

Comment: Does the code go into the `if` statement? Or maybe it just silently ends the function? Have you added an `else` to see if goes into that, as a test? And what about the response code, as I mentioned? That would tell if you there's a hidden crash somewhere, potentially.

Comment: I don't know where I can find web server config. I am using channel so if you can tell me where it is on channel I could share it with you

Comment: I added a `else` statement and yes, it doesn't go into the `if (preg_match('@^'.$url.'$@',$request_uri,$parameters))`. What could the problem be?

Comment: Well if it doesn't go into the `if`, then clearly preg_match returned 0 (which is false-y).  As to _why_ ...well that would depend on the values of the variables you passed into it. Have you checked that those variables contain what you're expecting them to? Post the contents of them in your question, so we can see.

Comment: @ADyson I added the values of them using `var_dump();` function to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Since `$request_uri` is empty, clearly it's not going to be able to match any values from within it. So now I suggest you start debugging the `parse_url` function to see how it came to be empty.

Comment: @ADyson i checked at my localhost and the value of ‘$request_uri’ is ‘“/“‘. do you have any idea why is it like this on live server? is it maybe because i havent done some configurations? i dont have much idea about have the ‘parse_url()’ works because i thought i wouldn’t need how the routing works, i would just need to know how to run ‘run’ function.

Comment: I don't know specifically.  That's why I suggested you need to debug that function, then you can learn what it does and what values the variables have. Compare the live values with your development environment